# SequenceGenerator is generating negative values and throwing EntityExistsException

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, oracle12c

I have defined my Entity bean as follows

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="PERSON_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name="PERSON_SEQ", sequenceName="PERSON_SID_SEQ")
@Column(name = "PERSON_SID")
private BigDecimal personSid;
```

I'm using Spring-data-jpa 2.0.5 boot application, with Oracle 12C database. Our DB sequence is defined as

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "PERSON_SID_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 
9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1
```

My application is required to do insertion of huge number of records, close to 6000 or more per every request and I may get parallel requests of such volume. To enable bulk insert, I have few settings

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
```

I'm also using jpaRepository.saveAll() for every 50 records and calling flush() after every 50 records. However, when I use sequence generator like defined above, I see only one

```
select person_sid_seq.nextval from dual
```

followed by 50 insert statements. But eventually failing with exception

```
javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same 
identifier value was already associated with the session : 
[com.sample.Person#1]
```

and not only that, I also notice the sequence numbers generated are negative values. As if they are not coming from the Person_sid_seq

I see the same behavior when save() method is used instead of saveAll().

But If I remove the @SequenceGenerator and @GeneratedValue, and set the id, before calling save, I do not see any issues with persistence (ofcourse noticing a select before every insert, not sure why).

But my intention is not to assign ID explicitly and let DB and JPA take care of it automatically.

1) What could be the reasons, the sequence numbers returned are negative ? Am I missing any setting?
2) Why there is an exception (EntityExistsException), when relying on DB to assign me a unique value from sequence. May be answer to 1, will also answer this
3) When setting ID programatically, why an extra select is called. ?

Could you please help me understand this ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried with @SequenceGenerator(name="PERSON_SEQ", sequenceName="PERSON_SID_SEQ",initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)?

Comment: allocationSize=1 helped and also hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false